# Not able to successfully do transactions of default MetaCoins(from Truffle) on local testnet on MetaMask

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, testnets, testrpc, metamask

I have installed truffle and ran the default contract provided by truffle.

I successfully compiled,migrate and put the default dapp on local testnet
http://localhost:8080/.I am able to see the dapp here.

I have also synced the metamask account with testrpc using 
testrpc -m "mnemonics"

But when I try to send metacoins to one of the account address present in MetaMask ,I do not see any confirmation pop-up of Metamask to Accept/Reject Transaction.Neither does the transaction details shows up in Metamask window.
Though, whenever I try to send metacoins from http://localhost:8080 ,it suddenly displays message "Transaction Complete" without any confirmation or any coin amount deducted from main balance.

Truffle version : 3.4.6
npm version : 5.3.0
EthereumJS TestRPC v4.0.1

Attaching few screenshots too for your reference. Please help.